# App on-boarding via contextual imagery

Tags: user-behavior, settings, onboarding, interview

I am in the process of identifying suitable methods for on-boarding users on what is in effect a "shopping" app.  I would like to configure the app to the needs of its current user by finding out what interests him/her.  One of the methods I am considering is depicted below

[image]

The key elements I am considering using here

- A contextual background image.  In the present instance a grocery store aisle
- A question with a small animated character (representative image shown) that acts as an "assistant" throughout the app.
- A simple choice of one-click answers

I should mention that prior to showing these screens there will be a simple animation outlining the key benefits to be had from using the app.

This is my first truly serious attempt at incorporating a planned on-boarding strategy in an app.  I'd appreciate any feedback on how the technique I have outlined above is likely to be perceived by users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I know the goal of these questionaires? are you trying to personalize the feeds base on user's choices or? You have mentioned that there will be a simple animation prior to these questions, so I was just wondering if the on-boarding flow is too long.

Else, using the contextual image for on-boarding is reasonable. Most of design are using illustration instead, it can give brand more voice. I will suggest to reduce the choice of answer from 3 to 2, when user see there is more "yes/no" choice, it might slow down their goal thus making the flow not elegant enough, maybe you have certain goal for these I'm not fully aware of.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Yes, the goal is to personalize feeds to the user based on their responses.  The initial animation closely follows what has been done by Dropbox in their app - 4 simple screens with line drawings. If I understood you right you are suggesting that using illustrations - as opposed to photos - is more conventional? Good point re 2 vs 3 choices. I had put in three since the feeds are personalized in order of presentation based on the often vs Sometimes response. The option would be a Green - Yellow - Red light scale but I am unsure that is evident without any text btns.